# broke my high Sierra

Tags: macos-highsierra

I had a Microsoft update pop up coming up at each reboot. I deleted some files (the Microsoft Update app and a file named icult59l.dat - found when looking at the process info to find the location). Since then, the macOS does not show up the login screen anymore (screen remains black).

Even if I use the safe mode, I got the same thing. I tried with the verbose, but at one point, the GUI loads up, which leads to the same symptoms. I use a single user, which works. I went to see the .Trash for the User and the deleted files are in there. I went to the LaunchDaemons and LauncAgents to delete the com.microsoft.autoupdate.plist and rebooted, but no chance.

I d like to move the files in the Trash back, but I am in single-user mode and do not know where the files were. Could anyone have an idea to suggest me avoiding to reinstall everything on my mac and avoiding me losing my data? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Microsoft update on MacOS? Please use the edit button and do a more thorough job explaining your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Look into reading the .DS_store file located in the .Trash folder. This file will contain list of the recently deleted files and their original location.