# restore /Users .trash files when booted in single user mode OSX

Tags: macos, macos-highsierra

I can yet only boot in single user mode as I deleted some files that prevent my mac to show the login screen ( I see a black screen instead). when browsing in the user .Trash folder I can see the files I'd like to restore as well as the .DS_Store folder which should contain the original locations. Is there a shell possibility to restore all the delete files when in single users? Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know of anywhere the .DS_Store format is documented, or anything other than Finder that knows how to read it. If you know where the files belong, you can use `mv` to put them back, but if you get it wrong you could well make things even worse.

Comment: Just boot to Recovery & lay a new OS over the top. That's what Recovery is for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [broke my high Sierra](https://superuser.com/questions/1480335/broke-my-high-sierra)